Sliding glass door "breaks" in extreme cold
Background:  in early 2022 we had a new exterior sliding glass door installed; it opens onto a deck.  (Product and installation from Renewal by Andersen.) We've been very happy with it, with one large exception:  if the temperature drops enough, something cracks and we can't close it all the way.  (We live in the Boston, MA, USA area.) No, it's not the glass cracking; something in the frame or perhaps the elements that provide a seal bend or crack.
It did this in early 2023; they came out and fixed it.  It did it again week or two ago when the outside temperature dropped to around 3 F; we called them today and they said they'll come out and fix it soon.
Given that we paid a pretty penny for this (in retrospect, it was REALLY overpriced!), we're not happy.
Most important, we don't look forward to this happening every time the temperature plummets.
It's clearly a design flaw.  I've looked at it and don't understand what's going on.  Obviously the cold causes it to contract, but it's unclear to me why that would put something under stress.
AFAICT what (probably) breaks is some metal or vinyl pieces that run vertically and lie between the moving part of the door and a stationary framed piece.  Unclear to me why that would break under stress, unless there are two such pieces that "clasp" and form a seal, then come under stress when things contract.
Has anyone heard of something happening like this, and what the long term solution is?  Couldn't find anything like it searching the internet.  Obviously I'll point out to the next tech they send that this has happened more than once, but I'm not betting on them offering a solution.
First pic:  the entire door. Stationary pieces on the left and right; sliding piece in the middle (slides open left from this view).
Second pic:  the back of the door (taken from inside the house).  Dark line is where the seal would be.  As I mentioned, I don't see anything wrong here.
(Right now the door is closed; I don't want to open it until it gets repaired, since I'm concerned it might not close again.)



A few pictures would help so we can see what you see.

Since the first time they were able to fix your door the contractor or their agent clearly must have understood what went wrong. You should be present when the agent comes to fix the door this time so you can engage in detailed conversation and observation so that you can end up fully understanding what the fix required. This will be the basis of further being able to investigate possible mitigations.

@MichaelKaras:  That's what I'm hoping.  The fact that this has happened two winters in a row (the second time a year or so after it was repaired) motivated this post.

It isn't clear that you have a DIY question. If you study the door's movement you might identify the mechanical conflict and could then ask here for help in permanently resolving it yourself. Identifying product defects and getting the manufacturer to address them, which is where the question appears focused now, really isn't what the DIY.se community is about.

Does it happen after when the temperature goes low enough to freeze water?  Maybe frozen water/moisture makes something stick together.

I have some experience with patio doors but I cannot make sense of your second picture. What are those buttons at the top? Is one of them a reflection? What is the framing material? uPVC? Fiberglas?

When the window people repair it, tell us what they found and did.

Knowing exactly what is cracking/breaking would help.  Saying something cracks, but not where, leaves us guessing.
